# When I set High resolution, the smoke disappears

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

This is a frame when I set the resolution to 32:
[image]

And this is when I set 200
[image]

How can I keep the smoke when rendering in high resolution?. Here is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJ50NZrlADRrVVbQjly4bLBWzMX5Jw3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've seen bug reports about _Adaptive Domain_ making problems in combination with _Dissolve_, especially when _Slow_ is checked. Maybe this could be a problem. Then your _Vorticity_ setting is much much too high, in combination with a short dissolving time it "blows" your smoke away... or it becomes very thin, maybe you need to set the density higher as well. Oh and the _Add Resolution_ in the _Adaptive Domain_ is much too high as well, as @Chris said in his answer.

Comment: Thanh you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded your file.

I changed the adaptive domain, add resolution to 5.

and with 200er resolution i got this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't understand what you mean, I want fire and smoke at 200 quality :D

Comment: you have 200er resolution. Please read here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/type/domain/gas/adaptive_domain.html#bpy-types-fluiddomainsettings-additional-res. -> this setting is for outside of your domain

Comment: yes, i got it. thank you so much. I found another problem. I scaled my domain to make it bigger !